# How (in what order, in parallel, etc.) does a browser load scripts vs other resources?

Tags: javascript, dom, download, parallel-processing, script-tag

### Givens:

- CSS files must be linked in the head element. Besides it making sense to include linked documents in the head element, this also helps prevent flash of unstyled content.  Their download will block rendering, but not DOM parsing.
- Script tags can also be included in the head element (with or without defer or async attributes) or near the body closing tags.  For the sake of argument, assume we generally don't put them anywhere else like the middle of the document.
- Browsers will download only a limited number of remote resources at a time in parallel (e.g. six at once, or even as few as two!) from a single host.  The limits are there to prevent server overloads, which is why sites will often host different parts of a page's content at different hosts, and why you should let Google host your jQuery: decreased latency, increased parallelism, and better caching.

### Unknowns:

The most interesting general question is this. What happens when a browser encounters a "script" tag in the head element as far as *download operations* are concerned?

**Script Download Priority**

First of all, we know that it will immediately block DOM parsing not only while it downloads but also while it executes, although modern browsers may may continue parsing and "look ahead" for other scripts or resources that may need downloading, to get them started as soon as possible. Fortunately, such blocking can be sidestepped with the defer and async attributes on the script tag, and defer will even preserve the script execution order (at least in theory, but lo and behold... IE9).

Assuming the script in question has the "defer" attribute, how, if at all, would it impact the download of any CSS files if they're linked before vs. after the script tag?

For example, suppose there are 10 linked stylesheets, followed by a script tag, all in the header and all targeting the same host.  Will the download of that script take precedence over the download of the stylesheets in any way (assuming at least one of them are queued for download), or is their download order strictly a matter of when they are encountered?  **In general, are script downloads prioritized over other content types (CSS, images, etc.) in any way in any browser for any reason?**  As a follow-up, does their download block any other downloads, even on other hosts?  I read that they may.

The implications of any such prioritization are myriad. I asked this question, because I thought putting the script tags in the head with "defer" could get them downloading as soon as possible, but if the browser prioritizes their download anyway, then there's really no advantage over just putting them at the end, which makes them function like "defer" anyway.  That would be great news if true, considering we shouldn't put them in the head with defer anyway, thanks to IE9's botched implementation.

Comment: Related: http://mrcoles.com/blog/how-tracking-scripts-affect-page-loads/  Scripts hosted on domains outside the site could be loaded dynamically after the ready or load event fires, to ensure they don't cause the page load to hang.

Comment: The feature where browsers "look ahead" for other resources to download while it should technically be blocking is called "the pre-loader (also known as the speculative or look-ahead pre-parser), and may be the single biggest improvement ever made to browser performance.  During their implementation Mozilla reported a 19% improvement in load times, and in a test against the Alexa top 2,000 sites Google found around a 20% improvement." http://andydavies.me/blog/2013/10/22/how-the-browser-pre-loader-makes-pages-load-faster/

Comment: It appears that implementations vary by browser.  "When the HTML5 parser is blocked, WebKit launches the preload scanner. This hastily parses the rest of the document, but without building any nodes or blocking for scripts. It only looks for potential resources and “preloads” them. This is technically a speculative load, because scripts might alter the document, but in practice it’s accurate much more than 99% of the time."  See more here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JQZXrONw1RrjrdD_Z9jq1ZKsHguh8UVGHY_MZgE63II/preview?hl=en-GB&forcehl=1#